# I am having an issue performing string matching within a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, jq

I have a simple script where I am attempting to extract the directory path of a package from a json file using a bash script.

I'm really struggling to correctly perform the check to see whether a string performs a substring within a for loop, using variables.

example below:

affected.json

```json
{
  "packages": [
    "package-1"
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "directory": "packages/subfolder/package-1"
    },
    {
      "directory": "packages/subfolder/package-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

main.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh

BUILT_APPS=($(jq -r '.packages[] | @sh' affected.json))
PATHS=($(jq -r '.tasks[] | .directory | @sh' affected.json))

for PATH in ${PATHS[@]}; do
  for BUILT_APP in ${BUILT_APPS[@]}; do
    echo 'path' $PATH
    echo 'built app' $BUILT_APP
    # Approach 1 
    # if echo "${PATH}" | grep -iq ${BUILT_APP}
    
    # Approach 2
    if [[ "${PATH}" == *"${BUILT_APP}"* ]]
    then
      echo 'it is a match'
    echo '\n'
    fi
  done
done
```

In 'approach 1' I seem unable to use the `grep` command, it results in `grep: command not found`

In 'approach 2' I just can't seem to make get the check to successfully recognise that the string contains the correct substring. i.e. with `package-1`

Any help is well received. Hopefully it's something simple.

Comment: `PATH` is a "special" variable which is used for command lookup and you're overwriting it. This is one of the potential downsides of using uppercase variable names. `| @sh` probably isn't what you want here as it's adding single quotes. `declare -p varname` can be a good way to "debug print" shell variables. You should also be able to do all of this inside of `jq`

Comment: As explained by @jqurious do not use a variable named `PATH` in your shell scripts. And using bash for your search is terribly inefficient. You could try `grep -Ff <( jq -r '.packages[]' affected.json) <(jq -r '.tasks[] | .directory' affected.json)`.

Comment: In addition to all the above, `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29). And if you run your code through https://shellcheck.net/, even after you fix the capitalization, you'll see it warning you that you need more quotes; it's `for built_app in "${built_apps[@]}"` -- when you leave out the quotes it acts like `${built_apps[*]}`, which is very much the Wrong Thing.

Comment: Also, you can't safely use `#!/bin/sh` with arrays. The `/bin/sh` shebang only guarantees POSIX-baseline features, and arrays aren't POSIX-specified; even when sh is a symlink to bash, it turns off some features when started under the `sh` name, and on many common operating systems (like Debian, Ubuntu, and Alpine) `sh` is instead dash or ash. When you're using bash-only features your shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/bin/bash`, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need bash/a shell here at all, nor multiple invocations of `jq`. A single call can solve your problem:

```
jq -r '
[.tasks[].directory] as $paths
| .packages[]
| . as $app
| $paths[]
| (
  "path \(.)",
  "built app \($app)",
  (select(contains($app)) | "it is a match")
)
' affected.json
```

Output:

```
path packages/subfolder/package-1
built app package-1
it is a match
path packages/subfolder/package-2
built app package-1
```

Comment: Is this using OP's `affected.json`? Can you explain your output?

Comment: @PaulHodges yes, this is using the `affected.json` from the question. What should be explained about the output? It is the output as required by the OP

Comment: Where is `package-3` coming from?

Comment: @PaulHodges oh sorry, thanks for noticing. I had added another entry while testing proper processing of multiple packages. I have corrected the output now to use the input file from the question (the filter remains unchanged).